# Jar files doesn't do anything and bat file can find the main class

Tags: java, batch-file, netbeans, jar

I have a java program I've just followed a tutorial and the .jar was created with Maven in Apache Netbeans 11. But the .jar doesn't execute... nothing happens. I even have a .bat file to run it but it says:Windows can't find file NewMain which is the main class.

This is the maven I've used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties> 
    <dependencies>
    <dependency> <groupId>com.apple</groupId> <artifactId>AppleJavaExtensions</artifactId> <version>1.4</version> </dependency>
    </dependencies>
       <build>
        <finalName>mavenproject3</finalName>
        <plugins>        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                <artifactId>mavenproject3</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
//Versión de JDK con la cual se ha construido el proyecto
// 1.8 significa que se utilizó Java8
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>            
                    <descriptorRefs>
//Sufijo que se le agregara al fichero JAR ejecutable
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>           
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
//Aqui se establece el nombre de la clase principal
                            <mainClass>com.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is there something missing or something misplaced?

Manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Usuario
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_231
Main-Class: MainClass
```

MainClass is not the main class

Update:
I've made the change

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Usuario
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_231
Main-Class: NewMain
```

Now: NewMain parent class not found or loaded

Comment: You can inspect your *.jar (which technically is just a *.zip) by unzipping it and check what is inside and what is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jar file should have `Main-Class: name of the class containing the main (with package name)` parameter defined in `Manifest.mf`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to diagnose in the following manner.

1. First run the .jar file with the command `java -jar <jar file name>`.
2. If it runs correctly, then the jar file is good.
3. If the jar file does not run, unzip the .jar file using 7zip and check whether main class has been defined in `Manifest.mf` file.

Again .bat file is a helping tool to run the jar file, it will have the same command as mentioned in point 1.

Comment: Unable to access jarfile mavenproject3-jar-with-dependencies

Comment: I did not get, are you not able to access or are you not able to open the .jar file ?

Comment: First no access, I´ve made the change to the correct main class and i´ve created the jar again, and now: class not found or loaded

Comment: As per pom.xml, it is `<mainClass>com.MainClass</mainClass>`, so you main class name should be `com.MainClass`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the package has to come first:

```
<mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject3.NewMain</mainClass>
```

Now It works